# Django check_password() always returning False

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-2.1

I have an existing database that is used with NodeJs application, now same database will be used for new application that is built with Django. 
I have an user_account table, which stores user login credentials, and for password encryption [bcrypt](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bcrypt) module has been used.**Password is stored in field user_password**

I have extended the Django Users model and overrides its `authencticate` method, which is working fine.
For password varification I'm using [bcrypt](https://pypi.org/project/bcrypt/) method `bcrypt.checkpw(password, hashed)` which is working fine too.

**Problem:** I want to use django `user.check_password(password)` instead of `bcrypt.checkpw(password, hashed)`. Since it will save the pain of generating salt and encoding before password match and most of all it's a built in method for sole purpose.

```
import bcrypt
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import check_password

#password = plain text password entered by user at login
#hashedPassword = Password stored in db (fieldName: user_password)
check_password(password, hashedPassword) #It returns False

user.check_password(password) # It also returns False

#for same password
bcrypt.checkpw(password, hashedPassword) # returns True

#hashedPassword format $2b$12$NNVaNL2Zla0E/WwC6Mkjjer6Qh3zIBCN6kMl9qxLE/xxyt4NAgXMq
```

I am using **Django 2.1** and
**Python 3.6**

I have already checked related questions, but all of them had issue with forms and I am not using any django form.

My `settings.py` hashers are as follows

```
PASSWORD_HASHERS = [
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptSHA256PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.BCryptPasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.PBKDF2SHA1PasswordHasher',
    'django.contrib.auth.hashers.Argon2PasswordHasher',
]
```

Input method is a simple django template

```
<div class='col-md-12'>
  <form action='/auth/login' method='post'>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class='form-group row'>
      <label for='email'>Email</label>
      <input type='email' class='form-control' id='email' name='username'>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group row'>
      <label for='password'>Password</label>
      <input type='password' class='form-control' id='password' name='password'>
    </div>
    <div class='form-group row'>
      <button class='btn btn-outline-secondary' type='submit'>Log in</button>
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Django does not store the raw hashes, they are prefixed with the algorithm (see [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/passwords/#how-django-stores-passwords)).

Without the prefix, Django will be unable to identify the correct hasher. If you look at the [source of `check_password`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/_modules/django/contrib/auth/hashers/#check_password), you will see that it returns `False` if it fails to identify a password hashers.

The cleanest solution would probably be [a custom authentication backend](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/auth/customizing/#writing-an-authentication-backend) with uses `bcrypt.checkpw` directly.

Comment: That also means, I shouldn't store new passwords with django's method `user.set_password`, since it will break the consistency, as existing passwords are saved without any prefix and i think djnago will save with prefix.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed the issue with:

```
from django.contrib.auth.hashers import make_password
password = make_password('yourpassword')
```

> check_password

and

> has_usable_password

returns proper values now

Answer (score 0):

This problem can be solved by installing bcrypt package using "pip install bcrypt" cmd

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).