# Issue for user from an existing database to login in a Django website

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, authentication, hash

There is my problem, so I need to create a Django app and I think I have to use an already existing database with users in. So I did some research and figured out some issues. So Django store the password with the salt and use it to check the password.But no one says that there will be salt + hashed type password in the database, but we can get read of this issue with the proper check function (related to the encryption function) I think, like this guy [Django check_password() always returning False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571170/django-check-password-always-returning-false) who used `bcrypt.checkpw(password, hashedPassword)` because in his database passwords are encrypted with `bcrypt`.

The solution proposed was to create a custom authentification backend (even if I don't really see how we can do this I may be able to find out a tuto to do so) but the main issue is that how I can save a user password who register through the Django web site with the same type of hash that the one already existing in the database (with no salt).

I'm a really sorry for not be able to give you more precision about how the password are stored in the database because even I don't know how they are.

Comment: This is really just a "how many users and are they easily annoyed" question. If you have a non-django set of hashes, you won't cleanly migrate them in - not a chance. the best bet is to migrate them into your new database and make every reset their password.

Comment: ok thanks for you help I'll try to do so.