# check_password not verifying database stored password successfully

Tags: python, django, python-3.9, django-3.2

I am using Python 3.9.7 and Django 3.2.7.

### Issue details

The following code is being used to verify the submitted password.

I can confirm that the submitted password has a valid value and `user.password` is a hashed password stored in the database.

```
passwordCheckResult = check_password(request.POST.get("password"), user.password)
print(passwordCheckResult)
```

Why does it always return False?

Hashed password: `pbkdf2_sha256$260000$Y0LeK0HJ90YPrj5lOijV20$oFRLMk`
Plain password: `123`

### What I searched so far

[Django check_password() always returning False](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55571170/django-check-password-always-returning-false)
but this is not fixing my issue.

The below code works but not the above one.

```
hashed = make_password("123")
check_password("123", hashed)  # This returns True
```

### Model

```
class tblusers(models.Model):
    user_id = BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    password = CharField(max_length=50, null=False)
    created_at = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Hashed password: `pbkdf2_sha256$260000$Y0LeK0HJ90YPrj5lOijV20$oFRLMk`

`max_length=50` is too short, causing the hash to be cut off.

Change it to `128`, like Django's [AbstractBaseUser.password](https://github.com/django/django/blob/0aa6a602b2b1cac6fe8e55051eed493b9cea7b81/django/contrib/auth/base_user.py#L47-L48).

```py
class tblusers(models.Model):
    user_id = BigAutoField(primary_key=True)
    # password = CharField(max_length=50, null=False)  # Change this
    password = CharField(max_length=128, null=False)   # to this
    created_at = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, blank=True)
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not using directly **User *check_password*** ?

example:

```
user.check_password(request.POST.get("password"))
```

here **user** is your **User** instance

Edit 1:

I will assume that **request.POST.get("password")** is returning a real value, try to strip the value like this:

```
check_password(request.POST.get("password").strip(), user.password.password)
```

if **request.POST.get("password")** is returning None, so double check if the input have the correct attribute **name="password"**

Comment: I am using custom method of authentication. So, in my case, user instance does not exists.

Comment: If the user doesn't exist, what is the value of `user.password` in this line? `passwordCheckResult = check_password(request.POST.get("password"), user.password)`

Comment: Check the edit.